# 'float' object does not support item deletion

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to run through a list and delete elements that do not meet a certain threshold but i am receiving error `'float' object does not support item deletion` when I try to delete.

Why am i getting this error? Is there anyway to delete items from lists like this for floats?

Relevant Code:

```
def remove_abnormal_min_max(distances, avgDistance):

    #Define cut off for abnormal roots
    cutOff = 0.20 * avgDistance # 20 percent of avg distance

    for indx, distance in enumerate(distances): #for all the distances

        if(distance <= cutOff): #if the distance between min and max is less than or equal to cutOff point

            del distance[indx] #delete this distance from the list

    return distances
```

Comment: The typical way to do this is build a new list without the items you don't want: `return [d for d in distances if d > cutOff]`. This also avoids modifying a list you're iterating over.

Comment: This may be an issue for me because i am also trying to delete two corresponding data points in another lists (if one data point is below the avgDistance then two datapoints in another list get removed). And i do that by using the indx in the enumeration to delete the two corresponding data points in the other list

Comment: `del distance[indx]` -- `distance` is a float, not your list `distances`

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake. But now this now brings up another issue, it seems that by deleting the items from the list inside the loop i am offsetting the deletion in the other list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list` of `float` values is called `distances` (plural), each individual `float` value from that sequence is called `distance` (singular).

You are trying to use the latter, rather than the former. `del distance[indx]` fails because that is the `float` value, not the `list` object.

All you need to do is add the missing `s`:

```
del distances[indx]
#           ^
```

However, now you are modifying the list *in place*, shortening it as you loop. This'll cause you to miss elements; items that were once at position `i + 1` are now at `i` while the iterator happily continues at `i + 1`.

The work-around to that is to build a new list object with everything you wanted to keep instead:

```
distances = [d for d in distances if d > cutOff]
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your comment that you need to reuse the index of the deleted distance. You can build a list of all the `indx`s you need at once using a list comprehension:

```
indxs = [k for k,d in enumerate(distances) if d <= cutOff]
```

And then you can iterate over this new list to do the other work you need:

```
for indx in indxs:
    del distances[indx]
    del otherlist[2*indx, 2*indx+1] # or whatever
```

You may also be able to massage your other work into another list comprehension:

```
indxs = [k for k,d in enumerate distances if d > cutOff] # note reversed logic
distances = [distances[indx] for indx in indxs] # one statement so doesn't fall in the modify-as-you-iterate trap
otherlist = [otherlist[2*indx, 2*indx+1] for indx in indxs]
```

As an aside, if you are using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org), which is a numerical and scientific computing package for Python, you can take advantage of boolean arrays and what they call [smart indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and use `indxs` directly to access your list:

```
import numpy as np
distances = np.array(distances) # convert to a numpy array so we can use smart indexing
keep = ~(distances > cutOff)
distances = distances[keep] # this won't work on a regular Python list
```